# Is it possible to update post meta from array in one call?

Tags: wordpress, optimization, updates

**Code snippet:**

```
$save_dbarray = array(
    'email'         => 'email@email.se',
    'adress'        => 'adress'
);

//Save values from created array into db
foreach($save_dbarray as $meta_key=>$meta_value) {
   update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value);
}
```

Is there any way to optimize above code? In this simple scenario, it wouldn't matter, but If I have a large array then I guess it might be performance issues when updating?

I would like to do something like:

```
update_post_meta($post_id, $save_dbarray);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I think this is the best way of going if you want each element under its own key (of course if it can all go under one key just pass the whole array in and then use `maybe_unserialize` on the other side.

I think using multiple keys is better up to a point though because it makes deleting them easier etc.

I would use your loop almost as is, but add in a check if the key exists, and use `add_post_meta` if it doesn't. You can also include a check for empty strings in your array and then call `delete_post_meta` if you like. Depends on what you want to do with this data later.

Answer (score 7):

While the other answers are creative solutions to your problem, they don't seem to address the actual issue or answer your question.

**The Answer**

No. WordPress's `update_post_meta` only works on one field at a time. Your best bet is to stick with the method you're using above, with the `foreach` loop. The other answers provide ways of storing that meta in a single field, which is probably fine for some but (as in my case) some need to query against those values, and having a serialized or JSON-encoded array doesn't cut it.

Unfortunately, WP provides no "bulk meta update" method, and if it did, it would likely be a `foreach` loop. You can always write a function to help make your code cleaner, at least:

```
<?php
function update_post_meta_array( $post_id, $meta ) {
    if ( ! get_post( $post_id ) || ! is_array( $meta ) || empty( $meta ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach ( $meta as $meta_key => $meta_value ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: `wp_update_post()` does [take a `meta_input` argument](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/631f08096bea41722a67e6b2e70d50ae0e2d3508/wp-includes/post.php#L4518-L4522), but internally it's just a loop, so there's no performance impact.

Answer (score 4):

phatskat is correct in that there's no built-in way to do this and a foreach loop is required.

This is the most efficient I've found - wrote about it in a blog post as well:

```
add_action('init', 'bulk_update_post_meta_data');

function bulk_update_post_meta_data() {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'POSTTYPEHERE',
        'suppress_filters' => true 
    );

    $posts_array = get_posts( $args );

    foreach($posts_array as $post_array) {
        update_post_meta($post_array->ID, 'POSTMETAKEY', 'NEWVALUE');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Why not try with [serialize()](https://www.php.net/serialize) like this:</strike>

According to [update_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) documentation you can pass the $meta_value as array, that will be serialized into a string.

```
$save_dbarray = array(
  'email'         => 'email@email.se',
  'adress'        => 'adress'
);


update_post_meta($post_id, 'my_custom_fields', $save_dbarray);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What do you mean that $meta_key should be? The meta_key is supposed to be email, adress etc...

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld i updated the code, where `my_custom_fields` is the name of key which returns you the serialize array, just unserialize it and use with array.

Comment: Hm. It does do the serialization/unserializtion part, but it does not actually do the update(s) to the db. And then I found that you should use maybe_serialize() and maybe_unserialize() instead when using WP. And I found that this serialization was made automatically!? http://nacin.com/2010/04/18/wordpress-serializing-data/

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld aah i missed this `(mixed) (required) The new value of the custom field. A passed array will be serialized into a string. ` for meta value, from the documentation.. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta

Comment: Yes, the new VALUE would be passed into a string. In your case the KEY 'my_custom_fields' would save the array $save_dbarray in a serialized string (if I understand the doc correctly). Unfortunelaty I haven't got your code to work.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld i am worried about the method that you implemented, take a look on this process it is similar to your one and hope its help you more http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Procedural

Answer (score 0):

Possible multiple value at a time you can your value genearte escaped_json

```
$escaped_json = '{"key":"value with \\"escaped quotes\\""}';

update_post_meta( $id, 'double_escaped_json', wp_slash($escaped_json) );
```

Comment: This doesn't really do anything that passing in the array and then using `maybe_unserialize` doesn't.

Comment: Additionally, you can't "easily" and reliably query on this style of data beyond a basic string match. The idea is that you can't do `get_post_meta( $post_id, 'key', true );` or similar with this method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one function that I made for bulk post meta update that you can use.

```
/*
 * Optimized way to add multiple usermeta keys and values
 * @author Ivijan-Stefan Stipic
 */
if( !function_exists('bulk_update_post_meta') ) : function bulk_update_post_meta(int $post_id, array $meta_data) {
    global $wpdb;

    $transactions = 0;

    foreach ($meta_data as $meta_key => $meta_value) {
        $meta_data[$meta_key] = [
            'exists' => $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `{$wpdb->postmeta}` WHERE `post_id` = %d AND `meta_key` = %s",
                $post_id,
                $meta_key
            )) > 0,
            'value' => maybe_serialize($meta_value)
        ];
    }

    $wpdb->query('START TRANSACTION');

    foreach ($meta_data as $meta_key => $meta_object) {

        $meta_value = $meta_object['value'];

        if ( $meta_object['exists'] ) {
            if( $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare(
                "UPDATE `{$wpdb->postmeta}` SET `meta_value` = %s WHERE `post_id` = %d AND `meta_key` = %s",
                $meta_value,
                $post_id,
                $meta_key
            )) !== false ) $transactions++;
        } else {
            if( $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare(
                "INSERT INTO `{$wpdb->postmeta}` (`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (%d, %s, %s)",
                $post_id,
                $meta_key,
                $meta_value
            )) !== false ) $transactions++;
        }
    }

    $wpdb->query('COMMIT');

    clean_post_cache($post_id);

    return $transactions === count($meta_data);
} endif;
```

You simply put an array with `'meta_key' => 'Value'`

Example:

```
bulk_update_post_meta( $post_id, [
    'ivi_test__1' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__2' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__3' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__4' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__5' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__6' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__7' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__8' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__9' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__10' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__11' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
    'ivi_test__12' => mt_rand( 1, 100 ),
] );
```